# Choosing a proper tolerance value in Logistic Regression (Scikit-learn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using the Logistic Regression model in Scikit-Learn (in particular, [LogisticRegressionCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html)). When I use the default `tol` value (which is 1e-4) and test the model with different `random_state` values, the feature coefficients do not fluctuate much. At least, I can see which features are important.

However, when I set a higher `tol` value (e.g., 2.3), each time I run the model, the feature coefficients highly fluctuate. When in one trial the feature A has the coefficient of -0.9, in the next run it could have 0.4.

This makes me think that the correct (or favorable) `tol` value should be the one when the results are more consistent.

Below is the related part of my code:

```
classifier = LogisticRegressionCV(penalty='l1', class_weight='balanced', 
                                #tol=2.2,
                                solver='liblinear')
```

I wonder if there are guides to determine the appropriate `tol` value.

Comment: A lower `tol` is almost always what you want, otherwise you risk the algorithm not converging, which is what I think you're seeing here. My suggestion would be to leave it as default unless you have some huge complex dataset.

Comment: thanks for your comment @ncfirth! I have around 12 features (my sample size is around 400). And, I wanted to penalize some irrelevant features strongly to avoid overfitting. I was increasing `tol` for that reason. Now, I think `tol` has nothing to do with this. But, I do not know. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah no I think you want to look at the `Cs` parameter. I would suggest starting with `LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=20, cv=3)`. Also you could think about some feature selection beforehand.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the info! Then, I should use higher Cs values to penalize stronger? I want to do L1 regularization, can I do it beforehand? Maybe, you should put together your comments as a answer.

Comment: I feel like we've gone off topic, so I'll just keep it in the comments, thanks though. A higher integer searches more values, if you want strong regularisation then I'd use something like `Cs=[1e-10, 1e-8, .., 1e-2]`. No you us L1 during the fitting, I meant something like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tol parameter tells the optimization algorithm when to stop. If the value of tol is too big, the algorithm stops before it can converge. Here is what the [docs](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L1359) say:

```
tol : float
        Stopping criterion. For the newton-cg and lbfgs solvers, the iteration
        will stop when ``max{|g_i | i = 1, ..., n} <= tol``
        where ``g_i`` is the i-th component of the gradient.
```

It should have a similar meaning for the liblinear solver. If you are interested in the details, the description of the newGLMNET algorithm that the liblinear library uses to solve l1-regularized logistic regression can be found [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf) and [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/l1.pdf).